# Android / Google Map: location change resets zoom and bearing

Tags: android, google-maps

I've integrated a map into my app where I'm updating my position as I move around. I want specific bearing and zoom level and I'm using bounds.

The following video shows the app with 2 location updates. Note how it rotates on each update. I want the map to move smoothly. Below is the method that I call on onLocationChanged.

[image]

```
    public void moveToLocation(LatLng currentLoc, LatLng targetLoc, boolean animate) {
    Location start = new Location("dummyprovider");

    Location end = new Location("dummyprovider");

    start.setLatitude(currentLoc.latitude);
    start.setLongitude(currentLoc.longitude);
    end.setLatitude(targetLoc.latitude);
    end.setLongitude(targetLoc.longitude);

    LatLng mid = new LatLng((currentLoc.latitude + targetLoc.latitude) / 2, (currentLoc.longitude + targetLoc.longitude) / 2);

    LatLngBounds.Builder builder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();

    builder.include(currentLoc);
    builder.include(targetLoc);

    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(builder.build(), 100);

    map.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLoaded() {
            map.animateCamera(cu, 10, new GoogleMap.CancelableCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                    CameraPosition cameraPosition;
                    cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder().
                        target(mid).
                        tilt(60).
                        zoom(map.getCameraPosition().zoom + (float) 0.55).
                        bearing(start.bearingTo(end)).
                        build();

                        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                        //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```